# Why "ended" event of audio html5 trigger more than once time?

Tags: javascript, html, audio

i have a code and i want to play the next track when the previous track is ended but i have a problem, when i start to play the previous track again the "ended" event trigger more that once time, i have no idea how to fix it

```
  AudioPlayer.prototype.listenToEndedTrack = function() {
    var _this = this ;
    this.audioPlayerUid.addEventListener("ended", function() {
       console.log("Ended");
      _this.audioPlayerUid.removeEventListener('ended');
    }) ;
  }
```

Comment: _this isn't the same object as this

Comment: Yes, it is. _this is AudioPlayer instance.

Comment: no, it isn't, they have different pointers

Answer (score 0):

You haven't removed the event listener because it needs the listener as well as the event type.

Based on your code sample, something like this should work:

```
AudioPlayer.prototype.listenToEndedTrack = function() {
   var _this = this;

   function listener() {
       console.log("Ended");
       _this.audioPlayerUid.removeEventListener("ended", listener);
   }

   this.audioPlayerUid.addEventListener("ended", listener) ;
}
```

Comment: Yes, thank you for your answer but it doesn't work if i change the timeline position

Comment: Could you post a jsfiddle with the code that isn't working? It would be good to see what exactly you are coming up against.